# /data/local/tmp/test error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have native executable on device at `/data/local/tmp` and using java api to run the exe  java.runtime.exec() method. However, I get permission denied error:13(stacktrace attached below.)

```
String runexec= "/data/local/tmp/test";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runexec);




Java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/local/tmp/test": error=13, Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:692)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:525)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:128)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Pro
```

Edit: `test` exe has `a+x or say 777` permission and functions properly via adb shell however, fails when invoked with java.

Comment: You may have permissions on `test`, but do you have permissions on every other segment of your path?

Comment: yes, I have verified folder and file permissions. The test works invoked with `su -c ...`

Comment: Verify that data, local and tmp are directories and that test is actually an exe (as opposed to a directory or some non-executable like a data file).

Comment: yes, I can list the file but cannot execute it.

Comment: What OS are you using? I think it's clear now that the underlying problem is OS-related, as opposed to Java. This sounds like it's going to be something weird, like a file system mounted with noexec. I'm quickly moving out of my depth here, so I suggest trying unix.stackexchange.com. I assume when you used `su` you used root?

Comment: I am using Android-8(oreo), yes su used for root access. Any idea how to detect/confirm if this issue is os related?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Android OS`. I had a similar problem on **RHEL**.
The secret was that **SELINUX** just **LOVES** to prevent stuff like this.

Check the log file `/var/log/messages` and search it for your executable name. You may find something similar to this:
"**SELinux** is preventing **pool-2-thread-1** from execute access on the file `<your_exec_here>`"

Comment: thanks for the delayed answer however, I cannot test and reproduce it on available android device. anyways how did you fixed SELINUX permissions?

Comment: @user755 That's a VERY long and complex story, but involves creating local policys with ausearch -c ... audit2allow, activating them with semodule -i, and also setting SELinux labels on some files and programs using semanage fcontext ..., and activating them using restorecon -v.
You can read some of it here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems
Good luck!